# MySQL Group by with Zero Count with Left Outter Join

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, left-join, where-clause

I have below query to get users registered for particular day, which works find except when user registration count is zeron for that day, i want it to show as zero count. However it seems to be skipping that entry,

```
SELECT count( * ) AS total, a.Date AS created_dates
                FROM (

                    SELECT (CURDATE() - INTERVAL c.number DAY) AS date
FROM (SELECT singles + tens + hundreds number FROM 
( SELECT 0 singles
UNION ALL SELECT   1 UNION ALL SELECT   2 UNION ALL SELECT   3
UNION ALL SELECT   4 UNION ALL SELECT   5 UNION ALL SELECT   6
UNION ALL SELECT   7 UNION ALL SELECT   8 UNION ALL SELECT   9
) singles JOIN 
(SELECT 0 tens
UNION ALL SELECT  10 UNION ALL SELECT  20 UNION ALL SELECT  30
UNION ALL SELECT  40 UNION ALL SELECT  50 UNION ALL SELECT  60
UNION ALL SELECT  70 UNION ALL SELECT  80 UNION ALL SELECT  90
) tens  JOIN 
(SELECT 0 hundreds
UNION ALL SELECT  100 UNION ALL SELECT  200 UNION ALL SELECT  300
UNION ALL SELECT  400 UNION ALL SELECT  500 UNION ALL SELECT  600
UNION ALL SELECT  700 UNION ALL SELECT  800 UNION ALL SELECT  900
) hundreds
ORDER BY number DESC) c  
WHERE c.number BETWEEN 0 and 364

    ) a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `users_tp` u
        ON DATE(u.register) = a.Date
WHERE
    ( a.Date  BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE() )
    AND u.origin_reg = 'mobile'
    AND u.step!=5   
GROUP BY a.Date
               ORDER BY a.Date ASC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from the `JOIN` : it is a `LEFT JOIN`, which is what you want, but then the `WHERE` clause refers to the table being joined : as a result, this behaves like an `INNER JOIN`.

To solve this, you need to move the conditions in the joined table from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`.

Change this :

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users_tp` u
    ON DATE(u.register) = a.Date
WHERE
    ( a.Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE() )
    AND u.origin_reg = 'mobile'
    AND u.step!=5
```

To :

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users_tp` u
    ON  DATE(u.register) = a.Date
    AND u.origin_reg = 'mobile'  
    AND u.step!=5
WHERE
    a.Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i have been pulling my hair out of this,

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

```
SELECT count(register ) AS total,a.date AS created_dates from 
(SELECT (CURDATE() - INTERVAL c.number DAY) AS date
FROM (SELECT singles + tens + hundreds number FROM 
( SELECT 0 singles
UNION ALL SELECT   1 UNION ALL SELECT   2 UNION ALL SELECT   3
UNION ALL SELECT   4 UNION ALL SELECT   5 UNION ALL SELECT   6
UNION ALL SELECT   7 UNION ALL SELECT   8 UNION ALL SELECT   9
) singles JOIN 
(SELECT 0 tens
UNION ALL SELECT  10 UNION ALL SELECT  20 UNION ALL SELECT  30
UNION ALL SELECT  40 UNION ALL SELECT  50 UNION ALL SELECT  60
UNION ALL SELECT  70 UNION ALL SELECT  80 UNION ALL SELECT  90
) tens  JOIN 
(SELECT 0 hundreds
UNION ALL SELECT  100 UNION ALL SELECT  200 UNION ALL SELECT  300
UNION ALL SELECT  400 UNION ALL SELECT  500 UNION ALL SELECT  600
UNION ALL SELECT  700 UNION ALL SELECT  800 UNION ALL SELECT  900
) hundreds
ORDER BY number DESC) c  
WHERE c.number BETWEEN 0 and 364)a 

left join 

(SELECT * from users_tp where origin_reg = 'mobile'
    AND step!=5) u

on DATE(u.register) = a.Date
where
(a.Date  BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE() )
GROUP BY a.Date
               ORDER BY a.Date ASC;
```